# Function called with too many arguments

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, exslt

I want to write a function in XSLT 1.0 using EXSLT library. Here is my stylesheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
    xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/">

    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <func:function name="my:test">
        <xsl:param name="param1" />
        <xsl:param name="param2" />
        <func:result select="concat($param1, $param2)" />
    </func:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="my:test('test1', 'test2')" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately when I try to execute it with `xsltproc` I am getting the following error.

> {http://www.example.com/}test: called with too many arguments
>   xmlXPathCompiledEval: 1 objects left on the stack.
>   runtime error: file exslt_function_test.xsl line 16 element value-of
>   XPath evaluation returned no result.

I do not see any error. The function is defined and called with exactly two parameters. Did anyone have a similar problem in the past?

To cut any unnecessary comments... No, I cannot use XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is a nice puzzle. Turns out libxslt (the processor used by xsltproc) will not execute the function unless you include `extension-element-prefixes="func"` in the `<xsl:stylesheet>` element.

Not sure why that is - other processors have no such problem.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 is a very tersely written spec, and it's easy to miss some of its subtleties, one of which is the distinction between the terms "element" and "instruction". Reading the definition of "extension element" carefully, it's clear that only instructions can be extension elements, not declarations; and extension-element-prefixes is not needed for vendor-specific declarations. But you have to read very carefully indeed to come to that conclusion.